Snowflake Kafka connector is up and running, but no data in snowflake tables
I have a snowflake sink connector, whose status shows up and running but no data in Snowflake table,
i dont see any issue in logs.
this is what i find in my logs
[2024-05-15 12:30:46,122] INFO [REFERENCES_ABS|task-0] Successfully created new JWT (net.snowflake.ingest.connection.SecurityManager:190)
[2024-05-15 12:30:46,122] INFO [REFERENCES_ABS|task-0] Creating a RequestBuilder with arguments : Account : abc123, User : DEV_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_SA, Scheme : https, Host : abc123.south-central-us.azure.snowflakecomputing.com, Port : 443, userAgentSuffix: SFKafkaConnector/1.9.3 provider/UNKNOWN (net.snowflake.ingest.connection.RequestBuilder:290)
[2024-05-15 12:30:46,122] INFO [SF_2024-05-13_REFERENCES_ABS|task-0] [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] initialized the pipe connector for pipe DEV_ENTERPRISE_DATALAKE_RAW.DEV_CRM_KAFKA_FINAL_TOPIC_RAW.SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_SF_2024_05_13_REFERENCES_ABS_533516335_PIPE_REFERENCES_ABS_5 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeIngestionServiceV1:46)
[2024-05-15 12:30:46,122] INFO [SF_2024-05-13_REFERENCES_ABS|task-0] [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Registered 14 metrics for pipeName:SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_SF_2024_05_13_REFERENCES_ABS_533516335_PIPE_REFERENCES_ABS_5 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:46)
[2024-05-15 12:30:46,122] INFO [SF_2024-05-13_REFERENCES_ABS|task-0] [SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] pipe: SNOWFLAKE_KAFKA_CONNECTOR_SF_2024_05_13_REFERENCES_ABS_533516335_PIPE_REFERENCES_ABS_5 - service started (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeSinkServiceV1:46)
[2024-05-15 12:34:15,433] INFO [SF_2024-05-13_REFERENCES_ABS|task-0] [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-SF_2024-05-13_REFERENCES_ABS-0, groupId=connect-SF_2024-05-13_REFERENCES_ABS] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1049)

Please let me know how to resolve this
I have tried dropping the connector and redeploying it but still it shows no data in table and same logs.
other connectors are working fine with the same configs.

Suspecting the issue could be , as the pipe and table already exists in Snowflake.
i have changed the table name in Connector and it was able to create that table in Snowflake and move data into it.

Did you check the table stage, if the data is present there?
